# What is a Kotlin module?

Tags: kotlin

In the Kotlin documentation they are mentioning some kind of *module* for instance in the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html) for the `internal` modifier.

However I couldn't find any definition of the term *module* itself. So what is meant by *module*?

Comment: When to use `internal` modifier? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47902656/kotlin-internal-visibility-modifier-in-android

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> A module is a set of Kotlin sources compiled together:
>
> - an IntelliJ IDEA module;
> - a Maven project;
> - a Gradle source set;
> - a set of files compiled with one invocation of the Ant task.

This is in the same [docs article](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html#modules) about visibility modifiers. :)

Comment: Now I feel ashamed. Seems they added that section just recently. My fault. Thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: could you be more specific, it is what in kotlin documentation, but what does it really mean.

Comment: For an android project, does that mean something declared as internal will be accessible for the whole android app?

Comment: @s-hunter, no, it won't. Android projects are built with Gradle, so the `internal` visibility means Gradle source sets (with the exception that the test source sets can access internals from the source sets they test).

Comment: @hotkey, I see. If the entire android project contains only one gradle source set, in most case it is for a simple application, then the internal means it is accessible for this entire android project. Am I correct?

Comment: @hotkey does it mean that you can declare a class that is only accessible inside a jar library in all packages?

Comment: Yes, that's mostly true: an `internal` declaration cannot be used in other *Kotlin* modules, but, due to the lack of support on the JVM side, it is still exposed to non-Kotlin code (e.g. can be used in Java code that depends on the JAR). The access is thus not checked by the JVM at runtime, as with private/protected/package-private declarations, but it's the Kotlin compiler that checks the access at the use sites.

Comment: hmm... jars support jigsaw modules, which can hide classes, does kotlin work with this feature?

Comment: @xenoterracide the Kotlin compiler doesn't generate Jigsaw module files. If you build with Gradle, though, there's an experimental plugin for generating them.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, so sorry for kinda reopening it; but does this mean that the definition of a module is "extralinguistic" in the sense that there is no way in Kotlin to define a module, but that modules are defined by using an external tool (Maven, Gradle, Ant or IntelliJ"?

Comment: @Gavin, yes, this is true, modules are not a part of the language. The tools that run the Kotlin compiler (either for compilation or just analysis, like in the IDE) tell it where the module boundaries are.

Comment: It would be good to see a coding example of a module & how "internal" works across it.

Answer (score 11):

From the Kotlin's [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html#modules), a module is a set of Kotlin files compiled together:

- an IntelliJ IDEA module
- a Maven project;
- a Gradle source set
- a set of files compiled with one invocation of the `<kotlinc>` Ant task.

That is **@hotkey's**, but I would like to complement this answer.

[According to Andrey Breslav](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/understanding-modules/474/2), the Lead Language Designer of Kotlin:

> a Kotlin module maps one-to-one to IntelliJ's module (iml-file).

According to IntelliJ's [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html):

> Modules allow you to combine several technologies and frameworks in one application. In IntelliJ IDEA, you can create several modules for a project and each of them can be responsible for its own framework.

When it comes to a Maven project or a command line compilation, [Andrey states](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/understanding-modules/474/4):

> Each compiler run, by default, is a separate module: all the binary dependencies will be treated as being not in the module being compiled at the moment.

Also, a Gradle source set is a module, with the exception that the `test` source set can access the internal declarations of main.

This means that if you have different build flavors in your Gradle configuration resulting in different source sets, for production and debug versions for example, then an internal class from one source set would not be available to be used in another source set.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Kotlin language specification §10.2 Modules](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/packages-and-imports.html#modules):

> A module is a concept on the boundary between the code itself and the
> resulting application, thus it depends on and influences both of them.
> A Kotlin module is a set of Kotlin files which are considered to be
> *interdependent* and must be handled together during compilation.
>
> In a simple case, a module is a set of files compiled at the same time
> in a given project.
>
> - A set of files being compiled with a single Kotlin compiler invocation
> - A Maven module
> - A Gradle project
>
> In a more complicated case involving multi-platform projects, a module
> **may be distributed across several compilations, projects and/or platforms**.
>
> For the purposes of Kotlin/Core, modules are important for `internal`
> [visibility](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/declarations.html#declaration-visibility). How modules influence particular platforms is
> described in their respective sections of this specification.

Answer (score -1):

I think you might be referring to `org.koin.core.module.Module`

A Koin module is a "space" to gather Koin definition. It's declared with the module function.

```
val myModule = module {
    // Your definitions ...
}
```

This [documentation](https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-core/modules/) would be helpful in that case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, I asked this question back before Koin actually existed, if I'm not mistaken. 