# Can't create private classes with same name in different modules

Tags: kotlin, name-collision

[Official docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html) on visibility modifiers in Kotlin say that package-level elements marked `private` are be visible only in the module in which they are declared.

So class `A` declared in `Module1.kt` isn't visible in `Module2.kt`. But if I try to add to `Module2.kt` it's own class `A` I get the `Redeclaration: A` error.

Since I can't access in `Module2.kt` to `Module1`'s `A` class, why isn't the name `A` free to use?

Comment: You're probably confused with what modules are, please check that your `Module1.kt` and `Module2.kt` are actually in different modules according to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35271413/what-is-a-kotlin-module). I tried this with multiple modules and didn't have a redeclaration error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"A module is a set of Kotlin files compiled together" ([Visibility Modifiers - Kotlin Programming Language](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html)).

In your example, `Module1.kt` and `Module2.kt` are separate source files and despite their names they are not necessarily part of separate modules:

- If they are compiled together then they are part of the same module.
- If they are compiled separately from one another then they will be part of different modules and each can define their own `private class A`.

Keep in mind that visibility is different from identity. Even if a `class` is not visible elsewhere it doesn't mean that it does not exist. Loading multiple class declarations with the same fully-qualified name can (and likely will) cause issues at run-time.

Comment: Seems like this makes `private` kind of useless, since it's effectively `internal`. I ran into this when trying to create a file-scoped helper class.