# Kotlin "internal" visibility modifier in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

Suppose you're writing an Android project (**not a library**). All the files are compiled together so... is there any sense to use an `internal` visibility modifier in this case?

Comment: Well, you could have different source sets for your app (e.g. src/main, src/release and src/debug). An `internal` symbol would only be visible within its own source set.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can have multiple Gradle modules that depend on each other within a single Android application, in that case, `internal` restricts visibility to within a given module. This could be useful if, for example, you have a separate `data` module that handles database and network tasks, and you only want to expose a couple interfaces from that module, but not their implementations.

Otherwise, if you're not using multiple modules, and your entire application is just in the default `app` module, then the `internal` modifier makes no difference in comparison to the default `public` visibility.

Comment: Had to use a `protected` modifier in Java for that (and deal with a package restriction). Kotlin's `internal` looks much better

Comment: What about framework classes like Fragment? They need a public constructor in Java. Since Fragment class it's written in Java, if we override a Fragment in Kotlin and we use "internal" it will work anyways. 
But is it the way go?

Comment: There's really no reason to change their visibility to `internal` instead of using the default `public` unless you want to hide them from another module.

Comment: To hide them from another module could be a case.
But also imagine if this fragment extends a "base class" that's generic and it takes some type parameter. 
If this class type is marked with internal and the Fragment as public, the compiler will complain.

Answer (score 6):

No, because you would only have one module. Take a look at the definition.

> The internal visibility modifier means that the member is visible
>   within the same module. More specifically, a module is a set of Kotlin
>   files compiled together:
>
> - an IntelliJ IDEA module;
> - a Maven project; a Gradle source set;
> - a set of files compiled with one invocation of the Ant task.
>
> ([Source](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html#modules))

`internal` only has effect across several modules.