# What is the difference between "package" and "module" in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, module, package, visibility

In terms of Kotlin, what is the difference between a package and a module?

When it comes to visibility modifiers for top-level code, the `internal` modifier only allows accessibility for code inside the same module. This makes it seem like package and module are the same thing but I'm not certain.

The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35271413/what-is-a-kotlin-module) does not answer my question as it does not bring modules and packages into the same context.

Comment: I've removed the duplicate vote, but I still think it answers the question satisfactorily. A module is made up of one or more packages. Kotlin packages are just like Java packages.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Short answer: packages collect related classes, and correspond roughly to directories; while modules are a much higher level and correspond to projects and/or compiler runs.

Longer answer:

In Java and Kotlin, classes are arranged into packages.  They're set using the `package` directive at the top of each file.  (In Java, this corresponds exactly to the directory structure in which they're stored; that's common in Kotlin too, though not strictly required.)

They provide a way of grouping related classes: you can refer to classes (and top-level functions and fields) in the same package directly, while all other classes need to be `import`ed, or their fully-qualified names (*package*.*package*…*class*) used.  And in the most recent versions of Java, you can ‘seal’ a package, which means no-one else can add classes to it later on.

Modules, on the other hand, are new to Kotlin.  They are a much higher-level concept, collecting together all the classes in a program or library.  (Some IDEs and tools call this a ‘project’ or ‘source set’.)  All the files in a module must be compiled together, and the results are usually collected into a .jar (or .war) file.

A big system might consist of a handful of modules, but each of those could contain many tens of packages.

Comment: could you give a compilable example?

Answer (score 7):

More specifically, a module is a set of Kotlin files compiled together. and it is on top of packages. Packages on the other hand, are folders that groups related classes.

Comment: please, how can one find this useful: compiling different sets of file differently

Comment: @EdgeDev Actually, these set of files are necessary in order to build your entire project or software, you can't compile them differently, they are part of your program.